# Is there a way to program the (Download) button to save a group of images as a one video?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ffmpeg

This is my entire code. Its function is that everything the user writes or says will have images returned to him according to what he wrote/said, and the next image will be shown to him after he presses “close,” and he can save each image separately. I want to make a simple modification to it. First, instead of a close button, I want each image to be displayed for 3 seconds and the next one to be displayed, and so on... “all of them in one window”, and for the “download” button to be when the last image is displayed, and for them all to be saved in one video.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart' as stt;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();
  late stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  void _listen() async {
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (val) => setState(() {
            _textEditingController.text = val.recognizedWords;
            if (val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence > 0) {
              _showImages(val.recognizedWords);
            }
          }),
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Viewer'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _textEditingController,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Enter a word',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                String userInput = _textEditingController.text;
                _showImages(userInput);
              },
              child: Text('Show Images'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _listen,
              child: Text(_isListening ? 'Stop Listening' : 'Start Listening'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Future<void> _showImages(String userInput) async {
  String directoryPath = 'assets/output_images/';
  print("User Input: $userInput");
  print("Directory Path: $directoryPath");

  List<String> assetFiles = await rootBundle
      .loadString('AssetManifest.json')
      .then((String manifestContent) {
    final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
    return manifestMap.keys
        .where((String key) => key.startsWith(directoryPath))
        .toList();
  });

  List<String> imageFiles = assetFiles.where((String assetPath) =>
      assetPath.toLowerCase().endsWith('.jpg') ||
      assetPath.toLowerCase().endsWith('.gif')).toList();

  List<String> words = userInput.split(' '); // Tokenize the sentence into words

  for (String word in words) {
    String wordImagePath = '$directoryPath$word.gif';

    if (imageFiles.contains(wordImagePath)) {
      await _showDialogWithImage(wordImagePath);
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
        String letter = word[i];
        String letterImagePath = imageFiles.firstWhere(
          (assetPath) => assetPath.toLowerCase().endsWith('$letter.jpg'),
          orElse: () => '',
        );
        if (letterImagePath.isNotEmpty) {
          await _showDialogWithImage(letterImagePath);
        } else {
          print('No image found for $letter');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

  

  Future<void> _showDialogWithImage(String imagePath) async {
    await showDialog<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: Image.asset(imagePath),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Close'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _downloadImage(imagePath);
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
              child: Text('Download'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Future<void> _downloadImage(String assetPath) async {
    try {
      final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(assetPath);
      final List<int> bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

      final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));

      if (result != null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Image saved to gallery.'),
          ),
        );
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Failed to save image to gallery.'),
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error downloading image: $e');
    }
  }
}
```